# TSQL: Find duplicate values based on two database values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I like to find duplicate entrys based on the same "Article" AND "Warehouse" column. I cant find a solution for an MSSQL-Query to find out the different "Value1" and "Value2" based on the following table:

```
Article     Value1     Value2          Warehouse
123         123        01.01.2021      1
123         456        02.12.2022      1
123         789        05.05.2024      1
123         123        01.01.2021      2
123         123        01.01.2021      3

456         123        01.01.2021      1
456         123        01.01.2021      1
456         123        01.01.2021      1
```

The result should be:

```
Article     Value1     Value2          Warehouse
123         123        01.01.2021      1
123         456        02.12.2022      1
123         789        05.05.2024      1
```

**EDIT: The Warehouse and Article is always different. In the result I want to the see the same article and warehouse which has different entry's on value1 and value2.**

As you can see the article "123" AND Warehouse "1" has different entry´s on the value1 and value2. So I´d like to get them in the result of the SQL-Query.

But the article "456" has the SAME entry's on value1 and value2 for Warehouse 1, so I don´t wan´t them in the result.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you should improve your question. It's so confusing. I don't unterstand the logic of the expected result and outputs aren't duplicate entries.

Comment: Hi @Datastorm1989 is warehouse value always 1?

Comment: "The Article(123) and the Warehouse(1) are the same." and "The article and the warehouse is always different of course." This is very confusing. Please explain the problem more clearly

Comment: I am sorry about this. The Warehouse and Article is always different. In the result I want to the see the same article and warehouse which has different entry's on value1 and value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT DISTINCT`.

```
select *
from mytable t1
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.article = t1.article and t2.warehouse = t1.warehouse
  having count(distinct value1) > 1 or count(distinct value2) > 1
)
order by article, warehouse, value1, value2;
```

(This would be more readable with an `IN` clause in my opinion, but SQL Server doesn't allow `IN` clauses on tuples like `WHERE (article, warehouse) IN (...)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.article = t.article and
                    t2.warehouse = t.warehouse and
                    (t2.value1 <> t.value1 or t2.value2 <> t.value2)
             );
```

It is unclear from your question whether *both* values have to be different or *either* value.  The above implements *either* value being different.

For performance, I would recommend an index on `(article, warehouse, value1, value2)`.